# MySQL join table query returns takes long time if no return result

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 tables named `host_order` and `host_order_line` as 1-n relationship. I would like to find recent update records on those tables and using this query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    ho.id
FROM
    host_order ho
    JOIN host_order_line hol ON hol.host_order_id = ho.id 
        WHERE ho.last_modified_date > '2022-01-01'
        OR hol.last_modified_date > '2022-01-01'
    LIMIT 100;
```

I have added index on the `last_modified_date` on both tables, so the query is quite fast. However it's suddenly slow if I change the query parameter which the result is empty. For example

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ho.id
FROM
    host_order ho
    JOIN host_order_line hol ON hol.host_order_id = ho.id
        WHERE ho.last_modified_date > '2023-01-01'
        OR hol.last_modified_date > '2023-01-01'
    LIMIT 100;
```

The first query is taking about 7ms, but 2nd query is more than 1 seconds.

I'm not sure exactly what's main issue and how to solve that query performance.

[image]

----Update
I add the sql create those tables here

```
CREATE TABLE `host_order` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `last_modified_date` (`last_modified_date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12267 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `host_order_line` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_order_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_last_modified_date` (`last_modified_date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `host_order_id` (`host_order_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `host_order_line_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`host_order_id`) REFERENCES `host_order` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=244811 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: I suppose the logic of your condition is wrong. You've forgot to add parenthesis, it's actually executing as `JOIN tbl ON (blabla AND ho.dt = '...') OR hol.dt = '...'`

Comment: Having `OR` in the join condition tends to be a real performance killer, and may also indicate poor table design.  You might want to add some sample data to your question.

Comment: When you ask about the performance you must provide complete CREATE TABLE for all tables and EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: You should add date condition with OR in WHERE condition rather then in join condition...e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ho.id FROM host_order ho JOIN host_order_line hol ON hol.host_order_id = ho.id WHERE ho.last_modified_date > '2023-01-01' OR hol.last_modified_date > '2023-01-01' LIMIT 100;`

Comment: Finally, I found an article about `bad` using `OR` in the where condition https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/

Comment: better using subquery

Answer (score 0):

- You can probably get rid of `DISTINCT`.  Having it requires that all the results be gathered and de-duplicated before `LIMITing` to 100.
- Perhaps you need an `ORDER BY`?  Without it, you can't predict *which* 100 rows will be delivered.
- The two queries differ only in date range?  Then the amount of data to work on is different.  This *may* even impact the query plan.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each.
- But the main problem is `OR`.  It does not optimize well.  Converting to `UNION` is likely to be the solution:

  ```
   ( SELECT   ho.id
        FROM  host_order ho
        JOIN  host_order_line hol  ON hol.host_order_id = ho.id
        WHERE  ho.last_modified_date > '2022-01-01'
        ORDER BY ...
        LIMIT  100
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    ) SELECT   ho.id
        FROM  host_order ho
        JOIN  host_order_line hol  ON hol.host_order_id = ho.id
        WHERE   hol.last_modified_date > '2022-01-01'
        ORDER BY ...
        LIMIT  100
    )
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT 100;
  ```

Yes, the `ORDER BY` (if needed) and `LIMIT` are repeated.  That formulation will need some index changes:

```
ho:   INDEX(last_modified_date)
```

And...

It smells like `host_order_line` is a many-to-many mapping table.  In this case, replace the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and the two current indexes with these two:

```
PRIMARY KEY(host_order_id, last_modified_date)
INDEX(last_modified_date, host_order_id)
```